# Swift Header Issue in Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

When I try to build my app with Xcode 8 beta 6(after converting my Swift 2.2 to Swift 3 using the built-in tool), the automatically generated Swift header (TargetName-Swift.h) has some issue and it is showing file not found when i import in my objective c header file
Note: It is working perfectly in Xcode 7.3.1

```
#import "Moji_App-Swift.h"
```

Comment: ensure once targert has added properly or not

Comment: confirmed target has added properly @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Swift-header may not be generated until all Swift files are successfully compiled. Try this: Comment out the `#import` line and all relevant lines till you can get "Build Succeeded", and then comment in the `#import` line and build again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once i solved all the other errors then this issue will automatically solved because swift-header not be generated until all swift files are successfully compiled.